# Resolving 'Browser Not Secure' Error on Mac When Using Selenium WebDriver for Google Account Sign-In

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I've been facing an issue while using Selenium WebDriver on my Mac to sign in to my Google account. I followed a tutorial that successfully resolved this issue on a Windows system, but unfortunately, it did not fix the problem on MAC m2 chip.

In the tutorial ([here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXy4I.png)), the presenter demonstrated how to create a localhost using Chrome Developer Tools on Windows, which allowed them to bypass the security issues when signing in to Google accounts with Selenium WebDriver. However, since I'm using a Mac, I tried to adapt this solution to Mac OS.

[image]

I have written the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


options = Options() options.add_argument("user-data-dir=/Users/username/Desktop/Local Drive/API/localhost")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
# Open the Quillbot homepage driver.get('https://quillbot.com')
```

After running this code I got:

```
SessionNotCreatedException

The SessionNotCreatedException is an exception that is thrown by Selenium WebDriver when it is unable to create a new session.
```

I believe that this is mainly because the browser failed to start or crashed during start-up. As this seems to be the case.

Could someone please provide guidance on how to resolve the "browser not secure" error specifically for Mac users? Any step-by-step instructions or recommendations for Mac-compatible solutions would be greatly appreciated.

I ultimately would like to use my google chrome without having to sign in each time I open the website using selenium.